# OpenEdge 10.2A - Generate database files using only .d1 and an old version of .db files

Tags: database, openedge, recovery

I have a .d1 file and an old version of .db file of the same database.

When I open .d1 file using a text editor, the content of the file is readible so it seems the database can be regenerated.

First, I have used only .d1 file and run the command under proenv:

```
prostrct builddb c:\db\myDb
```

the generated .db file only contains:

```
0020
```

string and nothing else, where as my standard .db files contains 640 KB data in each one.

I have tried to unlock my database using:

```
proutil unlock c:\db\myDb -extents
```

and pressed y for recovery question. And the output is:

```
** Database has the wrong version number. (db: 0, pro: 150). (44)
```

When I have put old .db file I have for the same database, and run the same command:

```
proutil unlock c:\db\myDb -extents
```

and pressed y for recovery question, the output is:

```
Database c:\db\myDb uses 32-bit dbkeys. It cannot be unlocked by this codebase. (13888)
Use the 10.1A prostrct utility to unlock this database. (13889)
```

I haven't seen the 10.1A version more than 10 years now and I'm pretty sure the version of the .d1 file is 10.2A.

If you direct me to the way to recover the database, it would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the .d1 file is truly 10.2a and you are using 10.2a to try to open it and the only thing missing is the .db file then you can properly recreate the .db file with:

```
prostrct builddb dbname
```

But if you are missing other critical files (such as the .b1 file) this will not work.

If you really only have the .d1 file then you almost certainly do not have enough pieces to work with.